# What is the use of 'fork' and 'executable' options in Maven compiler plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Maven-compiler-plugin configuration

```
...
<fork>true</fork>
<executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}\bin\javac.exe</executable>
...
```

Comment: When Maven build your code. It forks `javac.exe` process of Windows that is a Java compiler application for Windows

Comment: so the code runs even if the java is not installed in the system?

Comment: No, Javac program must be installed on your machine and also must be added to environment variables `${env.JAVA_HOME}` indicates the directory that you installed Java

Comment: Thanks El. Do you know any way to run the code without installing java in the system. like just by adding something in pom.xml file

Comment: Then how you suppose to run Maven to read POM file configurations if you wouldn't have Java installed on your machine?

Comment: ohh. Then I don't understand the use of above code

Answer (score 2):

Maven compiler plugin has a good [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) page explaining all plugin options.

> `<fork>`: Allows running the compiler in a separate process. If false
> it uses the built in compiler, while if true it will use an
> executable.
>
> `<executable>`: Sets the executable of the compiler to use when fork
> is true

Answer (score 1):

to add to [Saikat’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057554/1549977):

If `<executable>` is omitted and `<fork>true</fork>` is set, the maven-compiler-plugin will chose the `JAVA_HOME/bin/javac` binary.

If `<fork>false</fork>` is set, the maven-compiler-plugin will chose the compiler via the ToolProvider interface. This means that no new process will be started, and the same Java VM your Maven is running it will also do the compilation.

With `<fork>false</fork>`, you can also chose another compiler using the `compilerId` parameter.

Tip: Go with the defaults unless you have a good reason to change them.
The only good reason I could thing of right now [is a bug in JDK 16](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8253996).

Using another javac from another java installation is *NOT* a good reason: [You should use toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) for this.

Comment: another reason: if you want to redirect the compiler output with -Xstdout file, you have to fork to pass it that option. In fact, any non-standard options must have fork